# Word boundary between ASCII and Unicode letters in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, word-boundary

Python3:

```
import re
k = "X"
s = "X测试一Q测试二XQ测试三"
print(re.split((r"\b" + k + r"\b"), s))
```

Output:

```
['X测试一Q测试二XQ测试三']
```

Expected:

```
['', '测试一Q测试二XQ测试三']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`测` is a letter](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=X%E6%B5%8B#title) belonging to the `\p{Lo}` class and there is no word boundary between  `X` and `测`.

A `\b` word boundary construct is Unicode-aware by default in Python 3.x `re` patterns, so you might switch this behavior off by using the [`re.ASCII` / `re.A` option](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.A), or  the inline `(?a)` flag:

```py
import re
k = "X"
print( re.split(fr"(?a)\b{k}\b", "X测试一Q测试二XQ测试三") )
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LRBesM/1) and the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/szgnV7).

If you need to make sure there is no ASCII letter before and after `X`, use `(?<![a-zA-Z])X(?![a-zA-Z])`. Or, including digits, `(?<![a-zA-Z0-9])X(?![a-zA-Z0-9])`.